# Який більш сучасний синонім до слова "побір"?

Tags: синоніми

З сайту 1+1 [«Міністр освіти розказала про зміни в ЗНО, лінійки та побори в школах»](https://1plus1.ua/snidanok-z-1-1/video/ministr-osviti-rozkazala-pro-zmini-v-zno-linijki-ta-pobori-v-skolah?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=201805221959snidanok-FB)

Цікавить саме слово ***"побори"***

З СУМ-11

> **[ПОБІР](http://sum.in.ua/s/pobir)** перев. мн., заст.**1** У дореволюційній Росії — збір грошима або натурою (на користь держави, поміщика і т. ін.). **2.**
>   діал. Дія за значенням побирати. **3.** діал. Призов на військову
>   службу.

Насторожує помітка *застаріле*. Чи існує синонім до слова без застереження "застаріле"?

Наведені приклади в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80), як на мене, зовсім не відповідають значенню даного слова в відео (знач.1), а підходять лише для знач.3.

> НАБІ́Р заст. (призов на військову службу, рекрутування), ПРИЙО́М
>   заст.,РЕКРУ́ТЧИНА, РЕКРУ́ТСТВО, НЕКРУ́ТЧИНА заст. розм.,НЕКРУ́ТСТВО
>   заст. розм.,БРА́НКА діал. заст.,ПОБІ́Р діал. заст

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Зди́рство**, **зди́рництво**, **зди́рщина** — перший варіант [пропонує зокрема російсько-український словник Кримського і Євремова в ролі перекладу для російського «побо́ры»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B&dicts=1):

> Ніде́ нема́ тако́го зди́рства, як у полі́ції.

Другий і третій варіанти є синонімами до першого згідно до «Словника української мови» в 20 томах (*[зди́рництво](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=136899&page=1129)*, *[зди́рщина](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35676&page=1129)*) і [«Словників України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

Ще [на R2U пропонують інші варіанти](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), але я не бачу серед них сучасніших.

Upd.: Часто «здирство» вживають у вужчому значенні, а саме так кажуть зокрема про кримінальний злочин, що підпадає під [статтю 189](http://zakon0.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2341-14/page6#n1254) (офіційна назва — *вимагання*). Але переносний ужиток у ширшому значенні я вважаю теж доречним.